# Loop doesn't run every time (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create gradient descent using Python 3.x and PyCharm. 
Code isn't elegant, but it did it's work. But after running it for several times, "for" loop stopped working. 
I'm thinking it might be a memory issue or something like this, but if it is, I'm no sure how to fix it.

```
thrust_forward()
thrust = neu['d']
thrust_new = 0    

def back_and_forward():
    randomize_steps_effect()
    thrust_backward()
    thrust_forward()

    global thrust_new
    thrust_new = neu['d']

iterations = 5000000

def start_process():
    print('')
    print('Progress:')
    for i in range (0,iterations):
        global thrust_new
        global thrust

        while thrust_new < thrust:
           back_and_forward()

        thrust = thrust_new
        if i%(iterations/100) == 0:
            print('|', sep = '', end='', flush=True)


    print('')
    print('Final: P = ' +str(thrust/9.8) + str(prm))



start_process()
```

Main parameters are stored in dictionaries:

```
#Parametres
    prm = {
        'm':3, #kg/s
        ...
        'ph':-50000 #Pa
    }


    #Parameters steps
    stp = {
        'a':0.01,
        ...
        'ph':50 #Pa
    }
    #Additional vars
    neu = {
        'a':0,
        ...
        'd':0
    }
```

There is randomize function for steps, so "thrust" eventually increases and while loop breaks:

```
    #Randomize steps
    def randomize_steps_effect():
        for key, values in stp.items():
            r = random.randint(0,3)
            if r != 0 and (key != 'm' or key != 'w'):
                stp[key] *= -1
```

Forward and backward functions:

```
def thrust_forward():
    neu['a'] = forward_multiply(prm['m'],prm['w'])
    neu['c'] = forward_add(prm['pa'],prm['ph'])
    neu['b'] = forward_multiply(neu['c'],prm['Fa'])
    neu['d'] = forward_add(neu['a'],neu['b'])

def thrust_backward():
    global max_w

    neu['a'] += stp['a'] * backward_add()
    neu['b'] += stp['b'] * backward_add()
    prm['Fa'] += stp['Fa'] * backward_multiply_F_wrt_b(prm['Fa'],neu['c'])
    neu['c'] += stp['c'] * backward_multiply_F_wrt_b(neu['c'],prm['Fa'])
    prm['pa'] += stp['pa'] * backward_add()
    prm['ph'] += stp['ph'] * backward_add()
    prm['m'] += stp['m'] * backward_multiply_F_wrt_b(prm['m'],prm['w'])
    if prm['w'] >= max_w:
        stp['w'] = 0
    prm['w'] += stp['w'] * backward_multiply_F_wrt_b(prm['w'],prm['m'])
```

Comment: Looks like a problem with other variable values.You might want to show where prm, P, P_new is from. I am currently getting an error with these variables. I have also noticed you are accessing external/global variables in your function. You might want to minimize this practice and use parameters instead as that solution is not recommended and is only done as a last resort

Comment: Your code will be much more readable and maintainable if you used function arguments and return values instead of all those globals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "the for loop stopped working" ? it blocks at a given iteration or you get a runtime exception or you stop seeing improvement in the gradient?

If it blocks at an iteration is certainly because your inner loop never ends
`while P_new < P:`
since your P_new is constantly decreasing

However, the problem I see is that when you do `P = P_new` and then you ask `P_new < P` the last statement is always False.

If you could show the code contained in the forward and backward functions we may be able to help you

as Jeremy says, you should also avoid using global variables

Comment: Added some code. There's randomizer for steps' signs, used when going back through parameters. So eventually P_new ("thrust_new" in last edit) increasing if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: You were right, it's while loop. Something went wrong in randomizer. Thanks